# Use void pointer to store float numbers into array

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

I'm new to pointers and this may be a silly question.
Not able to store float numbers into float array using void pointer. Below is the code and the output:

Code:

```
int main()
{
int size=5;
float f_array[size];
populate(f_array, size);
// printing array below
}
void populate(void *p, int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        scanf("%f", (((float *)p)+i));
    }
}
```

Output:

//Entering five float numbers to be stored in array

1.2   // not able to enter other numbers and gives the below output

```
a[0] = 1
a[1] = garbage value
a[2] = garbage value
a[3] = garbage value
a[4] = 0
```

Comment: it works properly if you define `void populate(void *p, int size)` before the main, else compiler could assume int for all your parameters: if 64 bit compiler you're toast.

Comment: have you enabled the warnings? you should.

Comment: [mcve] please. We don't see how you're printing your values. My crystal ball tells me you're using `%d` format

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your problem.  Perhaps there is a problem with the print function that you did not include?

Comment: Code does not have any output code.  Source of "a[0] = 1
a[1] = garbage value ..." is not re-viewable.

Comment: Using below code to print
printf("a[%d] = %f \n", i, *((float *)p)+i);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 5
void populate(void *p, int size)
{
    int i;
    float *array = (float*)p;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        scanf("%f", &array[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{

    int i;
    float f_array[SIZE];
    populate(f_array, SIZE);
    //print array
}
```

Comment: at line scanf("%f", &array[i]); - it is required to use pointers instead of array

Comment: float *array = (float*)p; this is casting to your pointer, and arrays are pointers as well...